# TypeScript `extend` produces ESLint error when extending a template string?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want to implement a type TrimStart like this:

```
type TrimStart<T extends string> = T extends ` ${infer Rest}` ? TrimStart<Rest> : T;

type TT = TrimStart<'   Vue React Angular'>; // 'Vue React Angular'
```

But this produces the following error: Parsing error: Type expected.eslint

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the generic parameter `T`.

```
type TrimStart<T> = T extends ` ${infer Rest}` ? TrimStart<Rest> : T;

type TT = TrimStart<' Vue React Angular'>
// type TT = "Vue React Angular"
```

Comment: sorry，i copy the wrong code in this question. actually i define the type like this: type TrimStart<T extends string> = T extends ` ${infer Rest}` ? TrimStart<Rest> : T; and i copy the code you recommended, still got the eslint error: Parsing error: Type expected.

Comment: Hi @xiaoshumei. I copy and pasted your code into a [sandbox](https://tsplay.dev/mp97bW). If you click on the link, you will see that your code works fine. If you are still getting an error, something else must be going wrong. Can  you show me the exact line where the error occurs? Maybe make a screenshot and edit It to the post.